# Returning the Min() of a Count()

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, min

I am studying for an SQL test and the previous year has the final question:

> Name the student who has studied the least number of papers. How many
>   papers have they studied?

So far, this is the select query that I have created:

```
select min(Full_Name), min(Amount) 
from (select st.ST_F_Name & ' ' & st.ST_L_Name as Full_Name, count(*) as Amount
from (student_course as sc
inner join students as st
on st.ST_ID=sc.SC_ST_ID)
group by st.ST_F_Name & ' ' & st.ST_L_Name)
```

This works perfectly for returning the result I want but I'm not sure if this is the way I *should* be doing this query? I feel like calling min() on the Full_Name could potentially backfire on me under certain circumstances. Is there a better way to be doing this? (this is in MS Access for unknown reasons)

Comment: It does because there is only a single student to return in this instance. But what if I had multiple students with the least number of papers? From what I know, this would return only a single student and not the others. How could I write it so it would return all of them if there were multiple?

Comment: There are two possibilities: 1. use where not exists a student with a higher count of read papers, 2. find the minimum and join the table with the counts again to get the student names that have that count. Without `with` both queries are quite annoying to write.

Comment: Btw there is an inconsistency in the question itself: "student" and "has" is singular, but "have" and "they" is plural. (We would like to use `with` because both methods reference twice to the intermediate table with the counts, then we don't have to write it twice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only 1 of such students if there are multiple, this is probably the simplest:

```
select st.ST_F_Name, st.ST_L_Name, count(*) as Amount
from student_course as sc
inner join students as st
on st.ST_ID=sc.SC_ST_ID
group by st.ST_ID
order by Amount ASC LIMIT 1
```

However, if you want to find *all* stuch students, you follow a different approach. We use a WITH clause to simplify things, that defines a CTE (Common Table Expression) computing the number of courses per-student. And then we select students where their number equals to the minimum in that CTE:

```
with per_student as (
select st.ST_F_Name, st.ST_L_Name, count(*) as Amount
from student_course as sc
inner join students as st
on st.ST_ID=sc.SC_ST_ID
group by st.ST_ID
)
select * from per_student 
where amount = (select min(amount) from per_student)
```

But the real trick in that question is that there might be students that didn't take ANY courses. But with approaches presented so far you'll never see them. You want something like this:

```
with per_student as (
select st.ST_F_Name, st.ST_L_Name, count(sc.SC_ST_ID) as Amount
from student_course as sc
right outer join students as st
on st.ST_ID=sc.SC_ST_ID
group by st.ST_ID
)
select * from per_student 
where amount = (select min(amount) from per_student)
```

Comment: I've had to alter this slightly for it to work with MS Access but thanks for this. The With clause doesn't appear to work the same in Access.

Comment: @Syzorr that's right, the reason why I didn't make the comments as an answer... with the queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can order by `count(*)` to get the student with the least # of papers:

i.e.

```
select * from students where st_id in (
    select top 1 sc_st_id 
    from student_course 
    group by sc_st_id
    order by count(*)
)
```

if you also need the # of papers studied, then join a derived table containing the min count:

```
select * from students s
left join (
    select top 1 sc_st_id, count(*)
    from student_course 
    group by sc_st_id
    order by count(*)
) t on t.sc_st_id = s.st_id
```

Comment: This code would still only give 1 student if there were multiple with the least papers.